cue doesn't show all validation errors
When I validate a json file with cue, not all validation errors are displayed.
In my example "data"."structure" must contain only 2 fields: "f1" and "f2"
data.json:
{
  "data": {
    "rawdata": "some data",
    "structure": {
      "f1": "some string value",
      "s1": {
        "s2": 7
      }
    }
  }
}

check1.cue:
data: structure!: close({
  f1!: string
  f2!: int
})

When I run cue vet I get only one validation error:
$ cue vet data.json check1.cue
data.structure.s1: field not allowed:
    ./check1.cue:1:25
    ./data.json:6:7

After fixing it and rerunning validation I get second error:
$ cue vet data.json check1.cue
data.structure.f2: field is required but not present:
    ./check1.cue:3:3

What should I do to get all validation errors at one time?
I have a big amount of rules and big amount of configs. I'd like to see all errors to fix them at once. Otherwise, it will take several iterations to check and fix, which is not good idea.
I expect to see both errors in one run like this:
$ cue vet data.json check1.cue
data.structure.s1: field not allowed:
    ./check1.cue:1:25
    ./data.json:6:7
data.structure.f2: field is required but not present:
    ./check1.cue:3:3

